# Rotating image gallery with text and links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JavaScript that SHOULD work. I haven't seen it in action, but i hope it works.
The JS are supposed to choose a random image and then show the text belonging to that picture and this picture should also work as a link to another page.

BUT! I can't make it work! Are there anything missing or am i missing how to implement it on my site?

**!!SCRIPT UPDATED!!**

My JS - which i keep in a separate file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imagenumber = 10 ;
var randomnumber = Math.random() ;
var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1 ;

images = new Array;
images[1] = "img/rot3gal/cash.jpg";
images[2] = "img/rot3gal/carinjo.jpg";
images[3] = "img/rot3gal/casillas.jpg";
images[4] = "img/rot3gal/churchill.tif";
images[5] = "img/rot3gal/colman.jpg";
images[6] = "img/rot3gal/concosmos.jpg";
images[7] = "img/rot3gal/cooper.jpg";
images[8] = "img/rot3gal/corlando.jpg";
images[9] = "img/rot3gal/magicmemphis.jpg";
images[10] = "img/rot3gal/sidney.jpg";
var image = images[rand1];

links = new Array;
links[1] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/cash.shtml";
links[2] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/carinjo.shtml";
links[3] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/casillas.shtml";
links[4] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/churchill.shtml";
links[5] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/colman.shtml";
links[6] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/concosmos.shtm;l"
links[7] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/cooper.shtml";
links[8] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/corlando.shtml";
links[9] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/magicmemphis.shtml";
links[10] = "http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/sidney.shtml";
var link = links[rand1];

var Quotation=new Array() ;

Quotation[1] = "Volstrups Cash";
Quotation[2] = "Carinjo DVH 847";
Quotation[3] = "Volstrups Casillas DVH 928";
Quotation[4] = "Churchill EDH 475";
Quotation[5] = "Colman";
Quotation[6] = "Con Cosmos DVH 898";
Quotation[7] = "Blejsbjergs Cooper DVH 874";
Quotation[8] = "Corlando EDH 476";
Quotation[9] = "Magic Memphis";
Quotation[10] = "Sidney DH 412";

var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
function showQuotation(){ return Quotation[whichQuotation];}
</script>
```

What i use to get the image and link:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
document.write('<A HREF="' + link + '"><IMG SRC="' + image + '" alt="' + showQuotation() + '" border="0" width="110" height="90"></a>')
</script>
```

What i use to get the quotation:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
showQuotation();
</script>
```

Hope you guys will help me out, so i can get this script working :)

Comment: a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) might help explain

Comment: Have tried but jsfiddle come out with errors... The jsfiddle will therefore only show what is shown here...

Comment: The jsfiddle will provide a testing environment that we can use to work with though.

Comment: There is a really nice plugin available which you might be able to use if you don't want to write it from scratch. http://wowslider.com/rq/jquery-photo-gallery-plugin/

Comment: [This fiddle is the best i can come up with](http://jsfiddle.net/2M9dr/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see some semicolons missing in your external js file. What does the console say? And maybe it is better to have your function showQuotation() just do

```
function showQuotation(){ return Quotation[whichQuotation];}
```

Comment: Thx! Now it show links and the img alt-text and a "cannot-find"-picture if i remove the alt-text. But it's totally random?! But the quotation doens't show up. But it only works with your showQuotation() and the semicolons....

If Stackoverflow would let me, i would have edited the code in the question...

Comment: I'm not sure, if I am getting right, what is not working for you right now, but try in your last script part, instead of `code`<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
showQuotation();
</script>

to write: `code`<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
document.write(showQuotation());
</script>